# Error with Duplicate and Missing First Two Prime numbers

Tags: python, list, primes

The purpose of my code is to create a list of prime from an argument that determines the end value. My code fails to produce the desired result. I believe it has to do with my nested for loop.

```
def prime(num):
  primes = [2,3]

  for possible_prime in range(2,num+1):
    isPrime = True
    for number in range(2, int(possible_prime**0.5) +1):
      if possible_prime%number == 0:
        isPrime = False
        break
      if isPrime:
        primes.append(possible_prime)

  return primes
```

result:

```
prime(60)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 11, 13, 13, 15, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 21, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25, 27, 29, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 31, 33, 35, 35, 35, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 39, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 45, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 51, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 55, 55, 55, 57, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59]
```

I receive duplicates and I have to hard code 2 and 3 into the list

Comment: @ingvar Rolling back with edits to restore mistake in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong here
it should be written as:

```py
def prime(num):
   primes = []

   for possible_prime in range(2,num+1):
       isPrime = True
       for number in range(2, int(possible_prime**0.5) +1):
           if possible_prime%number == 0:
             isPrime = False
             break
       # Notice this indentation change
       if isPrime:
           primes.append(possible_prime)
    return primes
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Just indent properly and add one line to remove duplicates.

```py
def prime(num):
    primes = [2,3]

    for possible_prime in range(2,num+1):
        isPrime = True
        for number in range(2, int(possible_prime**0.5) +1):
             if possible_prime%number == 0:
                 isPrime = False
                 break
        if isPrime:
             if possible_prime not in primes: # add this line
                  primes.append(possible_prime)

    return primes

print(prime(60))
```

> Out[58]: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59]